# Replacing strings with other strings via Dictionary [Python]

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to be able to take user input and change the input using the provided dictionary for any characters/words found in the original input. However, the problem I'm running into is that it will replace subsets of words using other keys from the dictionary.

For example, btw should become 'by the way' but instead becomes 'bwhy the wawhy' because the function will reiterate over the translated text. The y in by becomes 'why' and the y in way becomes 'why'.

```
my_dict = {'gr8': 'great', 'btw': 'by the way', 'imho': 'in my humble opinion',
       'jk': 'just kidding', 'l8r': 'later', 'np': 'no problem', 'r': 'are', 'u': 'you',
       'y': 'why', 'ttyl': 'talk to you later', 'l8': 'late', 'atm': 'at the moment',
       'lmk': 'let me know', 'np': 'no problem', 'tia': 'thanks in advance',
       'brb': 'be right back'}

def translate(text, my_dict):
for key in my_dict:
    text = text.replace(key, my_dict[key])
return text

def main():
phrase = raw_input("Enter message to translate: ")
translation = translate(phrase,my_dict)
print "Translated message: %s" % translation

main()
```

I'd rather not introduce new functions / methods. I'm aware this can be done using re but I'd prefer not to rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `text` using `str.split()` , and then for each word in text, get either its value from the `dict` or if no such value exists get the word directly.

You can use `dict.get()` for that, and supply the word itself as second argument (second argument denotes the default value to pass back if the key does not exist).

Code -

```
def translate(text, dict):
    texts = text.split()
    return ' '.join(dict.get(word,word) for word in texts)
```

Also, you should not use `dict` as variable name as it is also the name of the builtin function to create dictionary , and using that variable name shadows the builtin function.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def translate(text, dict):
...     texts = text.split()
...     return ' '.join(dict.get(word,word) for word in texts)
...
>>> def main():
...     phrase = input("Enter message to translate: ")
...     translation = translate(phrase,dict)
...     print("Translated message: %s" % translation)
...
>>> dict = {'gr8': 'great', 'btw': 'by the way', 'imho': 'in my humble opinion',
...        'jk': 'just kidding', 'l8r': 'later', 'np': 'no problem', 'r': 'are', 'u': 'you',
...        'y': 'why', 'ttyl': 'talk to you later', 'l8': 'late', 'atm': 'at the moment',
...        'lmk': 'let me know', 'np': 'no problem', 'tia': 'thanks in advance',
...        'brb': 'be right back'}
>>>
>>>
>>> main()
Enter message to translate: Hello brb abtw
Translated message: Hello be right back abtw
```

Comment: Running the program throws a whole bunch of syntax errors. Why did you get rid of the for loop?

Comment: Don't run my example , it's written for Python. Replace your translate function with the one I gave .

Comment: Its written for Python 3.x , run the translate function I gave at top.

Answer (score 0):

This version of `translate` method will do the job:

```
def translate(text, dict):
        for key in dict:
                if ' '+key in text or text.startswith(key):
                        text = text.replace(key, dict[key])
        return text
```

**Explanation**: A normal English sentence will have `whitespaces` before any meaningful word. So, it checks if spaces are present OR if the sentence starts with the keyword itself (in this case, it'll have no spaces before it).

Input: `btw that was a gr8 day!`

Output: `by the way that was a great day!`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace without splitting you will have to use a regex with *word boundaries*:

```
from re import sub
def translate(text, my_dict):
    for key in my_dict:
        text = sub(r"\bkey\b", my_dict[key], text)
    return text
```

You can also compile the patterns in your dict to speed up the replacing:

```
import re

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[re.compile(r"\b{}\b".format(k))] = v
    del my_dict[k]

def translate(text, my_dict):
    for key, v in my_dict.items():
        text = key.sub(v, text)
    return text

def main():
    phrase = raw_input("Enter message to translate: ")
    translation = translate(phrase,my_dict)
    print "Translated message: %s" % translation
```

Output:

```
Enter message to translate: btw
Translated message: by the way
```

If you are going to split you should pass the delimiter to preserve the whitespace, keep words not in your dict as is or replace them with `my_dict[word]` if they are in the dict:

```
def translate(text, my_dict):
    text = text.split(" ")
    return "".join([my_dict[word] if word in text else word for word in text])

def main():
    phrase = raw_input("Enter message to translate: ")
    translation = translate(phrase,my_dict)
    print "Translated message: %s" % translation

main()
```

Output:

```
Enter message to translate: btw
Translated message: by the way
```